# How to forbid second user registration in PHP

Tags: php, project, registration

I`m making a project that contains user registration, but there is a problem. How can I prevent multi-accounting?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can't completely. There is some way I know

- Store in session, deny register when session is set - > User can clear session to register
- Require email confirm -> User can fake email to register more
- Store user IP and disabled register for a period of time -> User can fake IP using proxy and continue

Answer (score 0):

@Trinh Hoang Nhu is right...
You can log user IP on login, and then see if there is multiple accounts.